# Is an asynchronous counter made in Verilog synthesizable?

Tags: asynchronous, verilog, xilinx, vivado

the question in it itself is simple. Is it possible to synthesize an Asynchronous counter in Verilog?

More explanation:

So for example, if I have something like the following code, is it possible to synthesize it?

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  //rst
  if(!rst)begin
    enable <=0;
  end else begin
    enable <= 1;
  end

end

//action loop
always @(state) begin
  case (state)
    0:begin
      cnt <= cnt
    end      
    1: begin
      cnt <= cnt + 1;
      next_state <= 1;
    end
    default: begin
      cnt <= cnt;
    end 
  endcase
end

//state loop
always @(next_state, control, enable) begin
  if(enable)begin

    if(!control) begin
      state <= next_state;
    end else begin
      state <= 0;
    end

  end
  
end
```

Here the general idea is that the counter will go asynchronously while the input control flag is 0, if it is 1 then the counter will be stopped until the input control flag becomes 0 again.

Note: I know I could try and synthesize the code and see what happens. But before that, I would like to know more and see if people have tried it.

Thanks for reading!!

Comment: There is nothing *asynchronous* in this code.  It looks synthesizable, but you should always try to synthesize. Different synthesis tools behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

Your action loop can't be properly synthesized.
What it is doing when state == 1?

Your state loop is synthesizable except but you will produce a latch (to store the value when enable == 0). This block is something that could be done using combinational logic '=' instead of non-blocking assignment '<='.